# Unable to obtain stable ff connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I am getting the following error when running any Ruby script using Cucumber:

```
unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

I tried updating all Ruby gems using `gem install rubygems-update` but still have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks no way I could have easily searched for that, answer is good to know will use chrome for now

Comment: `gem install rubygems-update` doesn't update all gems. [The documentation](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update/versions/2.6.4) clearly says: `RubyGems is a package management framework for Ruby. This gem is an update for the RubyGems software.`.